# Regex for Startswith in Url for Typescript

Tags: regex, angular, mocking

I have a mock data service in Angular which is being called by below code to search for any items starting with what user specified (i.e. search_string). When user specified special characters like * and () it takes the whole string as regex and breaks. Is there a way to treat anything after ^ as a string and not regex?

```
this.httpClient.get(this.url + 'products/?productName=^' + search_string);
```

when user enters *** - it throws following error:  Invalid regular expression: /^***/: Nothing to repeat"